# specify wheel cache when installing a package

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

With the introduction of Python's wheel, I now see that wheels built are cached in my home directory's cache:

```
~/myproject-0.1$ pip install .
Building wheels for collected packages: myproject  
Processing /home/oz123/pyproject-0.1 
Building wheels for collected packages: myproject 
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for myproject 
 Stored in directory: /home/oz123/.cache/pip/wheels/64/80/bf/d7899de05c2cf7f1ae18806b0c494b8c43721189bbfafce32
Successfully built myproject
```

I would like to know:

1. Is there a way to install the project without building a wheel ? (I know I could simply remove wheel from my system)
2. Is there a way to specify the location of this cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the wheel cache you can simply do:

```
sudo pip install . --no-cache-dir
```